# Keylogger or Knowing the mostly pressed button in Android app (Eclipse)

Tags: android, eclipse

I want to develop an Android app in which I have key log press. In layman language, I want to keep track of the all the Buttons that I have pressed on my Android App so that I can make FAVORITE column. In FAVORITE, it stores the data of all the most frequently used button.

For example, on YouTube.com as well there is a separate Favorite Tab that keep tracks of most frequently watched videos or related videos. If anyone can help me, please share.

Comment: Understanding the very basics of the Android Fundamental's would be enough to know how to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your part, I would just make singleton class, where i save some kind of counters list (better hashmap, where `Button` is key and `int` is value of presses). Then increase counter in that singleton in every click listener. Then in favorites screen, you can find which button has biggest number (clicks)

P.S. this is for temporary storage. If you want permanent storage, use sqlite database for that